# "widely applicable" vs "broadly applicable"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which one is right:

> My long-term conception for a ***widely*** applicable next-generation software-uninstaller is to observe the programs under installation carefully and fully. In this context, ***wide*** applicability means that as many programs as possible will be correctly tracked and, when necessary, uninstalled.
>
> My long-term conception for a ***broadly*** applicable next-generation software-uninstaller is to observe the programs under installation carefully and fully. In this context, ***broad*** applicability means that as many programs as possible will be correctly tracked and, when necessary, uninstalled.

Why?

The bold-and-italics marking is mine (i.e., it does not occur in the original text).

Comment: Vasili, I will repeat my advice: find yourself an English editor for this. The word conception is misused.

Answer (score 1):

The two phrases you write mean nearly the same thing. As an editor, I would not say one or the other is more "right."

Widely applicable: can be applied in a wide variety of cases.

Broadly applicable: can be applied across a range of cases.

If there's any difference, it's in tone rather than substance, in my opinion.

From Webster's NW Dictionary:

Widely (adv.): 2 - Over a large area; to a large or full extent.

Broadly (adv.) 6 - Wide in range...

In Webster's definitions, 'broad' has a few more distinct meanings than 'wide' does. "Broad comedy" (obvious, not sophisticated humor); "broad daylight" (fully light), for example.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the text slightly and added one more sentence; perhaps it would help to determine which word sounds better.

Comment: @VasiliPupkin if forced to choose I'd go with **broadly**, but not because it changes the meaning in any way.  It just sounds slightly better to my ear, possibly because *broadly* is used less often than *widely*.